# If i add my wife as a cosigner to my bank account do i need to discuss my bank account in my will?

Tags: texas, wills, estate-planning

I was looking at [this Supreme Court of Texas document approving revised will forms](https://www.txcourts.gov/media/1456774/239037.pdf) and was wondering if a bank account that I recently added my wife to as a cosigner needed to be listed as a "specific gift" for her as well.

The fact that she's a cosigner means that when I die she'll be able to have immediate access to the funds after I die without having to go through probate. That makes it seem like the account doesn't need to be mentioned in the will at all, but maybe it still does?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a distinction between a co-owner of an account and a co-signer for convenience. In all likelihood, you have made your spouse a co-owner of the account, but you need to be clear what has been done.

If someone is a co-owner of the account, then the account passes by operation of law at death to the surviving co-owner in a non-probate transfer and is not controlled by the language of the will, or of any intestacy statute if there is not a will.

A mere co-signer does not having any ownership rights in the account and is functionally a mere power of attorney holder over the account. In that case, the will governs the disposition of the account. If you want it to pass to a spouse, you need to say so, unless your spouse is your sole beneficiary under the will, in which case there is no need to single out a particular account.